# What is the sequence about bluez ble mesh interface as a provisioner?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, provisioning, bluez, mesh-network

The latest bluez supports ble mesh interfaces (APIs). But, I don't know exactly what is the sequence that I should call by using these interfaces as a provisioner.

First, I can start to call `UnprovisionedScan()` and `CreateNetwork` and `AddNode`... and some authentication and provisioning interfaces. Could you guide me to the correct method calling sequence?